# Pure CSS to style text in table cell based on value in that cell - can't use script

Tags: html, css

I have searched the forum and found many older threads that indicate this is not possible with pure CSS (the system I'm using doesn't support script). I'm hoping perhaps it is now possible ... or someone else has another idea?

In the following table, I need to style the Green cell and Red cell with their respective colors.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Green</td>
<td>Red</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

The examples I have found so far each used script of some kind ... which doesn't help me.

Suggestions?

Comment: Yea.. still not possible.. check this out though.. http://jsfiddle.net/MNeXD/

Comment: Why would you ever need to do this? It'd be so much easier to just do `<td class="green">Green</td>`, and then style that class.

Comment: If there is no scripting involved, why would you need something dynamic like this?

Comment: +1 @BlakeMann Nope...i don't believe this will ever be possible...if the data is generated using server side technology like php or so i would suggest you go with BlakeMann answer

Comment: Also check out.. http://jsfiddle.net/MNeXD/1/

Comment: Thanks all ... JoshC's second suggestion shows promise. Is adding Green to the mix as simple as also adding:
`[color="green"]:after {
    content:"Green";
    color:green;
}`

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible, and it is unlikely that it will ever be. Is there some reason why you can't give the elements different classes for different colors?

Comment: This is a totally valid requirement. I need to do this. I'm reading a status of 'Complete' or 'Draft' from the DB and I want to style 'Complete' as green and 'Draft' as orange. I could of course return the value from the DB as '<td class="green">Complete</td>' but that's kind of smelly.

Answer (score 0):

although this question was asked long ago, but it's higher in google search. So anyone who lands on this page, here is my solutions

simply use the

`'<td class="complete">Complete</td>'`

instead of `'<td class="green">Complete</td>'`
and then style your "complete" class.